# WKHTML + Windows + PHP

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I installed wkhtml from here http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list (specically the wkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-installer.exe for Windows). I called ir from the command line and it worked perfect, but when I try to call it using the PHP exec or shell_exec function, it only works if the wkhtmltopdf.exe is located in the same directory my php is.

So, if I do this:

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.html c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.pdf");
```

and the wkhtmltopdf file is in the c:/wamp/www/test directory it works perfect, but if I do this:

```
exec("C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.html c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.pdf");
```

it doesn't work at all.

Can you help me? I'd like to make it work even when it's in another directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You have to put the path in quotes beacause of the space.

```php
exec('"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe" c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.html c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.pdf');
```

Alternatively you could just add the wkhtmltopdf directory to your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) , will make life easier for generating pdf using wkhtmltpdf

Answer (score 0):

change your exec coding like this.it works for me.:)

```
exec("C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe" c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.html "c:/wamp/www/test/pdf.pdf");
```

Happy coding...:) :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
exec('"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe" "c:/wamp/www/catalogo_2.html" "c:/wamp/www/pdf.pdf"');
```